# Sending out WP Posts as MailChimp Newsletters

Tags: newsletter, plugin-mailchimp

I have the functioning signup MailChimp plugin/widget working great on my customer's WordPress site.

But what I REALLY want to do is send out new posts (from WordPress Dashboard) as the MailChimp designed Newsletters.  Is it possible to do this?  If so, does it happen in the Dashboard or the MailChimp admin site?

Comment: Please add a link to the plugin you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Set up an RSS campaign in MailChimp and use the rss feed from your wordpress site for the campaign content.  If you don't want to include every post that would make it into your site's rss feed, you'll need to create an rss feed that's limited to just the posts you do want to go out.  *how to create a limited rss feed should be a separate question, if you needed help with that*  [See this page for a more details.](http://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/)

Comment: You can also combine multiple feeds here http://www.chimpfeedr.com/